# How to fix "'int' object is not subscriptable" in this case?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm just trying to write recursive code, but I've got this error. Where is my mistake?

I've tried to identify all the variables but it isn't working.

```
def sum(arr):
    if len(arr) > 1:
        answer = int(arr.pop()[0] + sum(arr))
        return answer
    else:
        return arr[0]

print(str(sum([1, 45])))
```

I expect recursion work properly but it doesn't. It has to give sum of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arr.pop` returns and removes the last element of the list. So it returns an int, not a list of ints.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html#array.array.pop

Here is how I would fix your code. I just remove the `[0]` from arr.pop() which fixes the code and also remove some unnecessary casting

```
def sum(arr):
    if len(arr) > 1:
        answer = arr.pop() + sum(arr)
        return answer
    else:
        return arr[0]

print(sum([1, 45]))
```